Following link overrides permission on target?
On Ubuntu 22.04, I did chmod 700 firefox from administrator/root.
As another user, if I type /usr/bin/firefox it correctly says "permissions denied". But if I just type "firefox" it appears to follow the link
/snap/bin/firefox and then the program starts without problem?
In general, I'm trying to block firefox for a specific non-admin user, but maybe snap causes problems?

Assuming you are using the default installed Firefox it is a snap the second path in your question is the correct path. So it is doing what it should following the snap path and running.

Yes.  How do I prevent a user from running it?
